# Scope doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to set a scope for a different route but it seems not working...

```js
var app = angular.module('AngularApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'menu.html',
    controller: 'MenuController'
  }).when('/slides/:menuItem', {
    templateUrl: 'slides.html',
    controller: 'SlidesController'
  });
});

app.controller('MenuController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('database.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.bottomBar = 'no';
    $scope.pageClass = 'menus';
    $scope.database = response.data;
  });
});

app.controller('SlidesController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('database.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.bottomBar = 'yes';
    $scope.pageClass = 'slides';
    $scope.database = _.find(response.data.menuItems, {'url': $routeParams.menuItem});
  });
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="AngularApp">
<div class="line">
  <div class="col-12">
    <a href="/pages/#/" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page {{pageClass}}" ng-view></div>

<div class="bottom-bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/pages/#/">Retour {{bottomBar}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

`bottomBar` is empty...

Comment: Your different scope doesn't defined this part of DOM.

Comment: Edit on post ;) I added `ng-app` on the dom..

Comment: The reason `bottomBar` is empty is because it's outisde the `<div>` that contains your view, therefor it's outside the scope provided by your controllers. You'll either need to refactor that or create an overall all-encompassing controller that everything else becomes a child of.

Comment: You should look to correct your snippet so that it runs and that we can diagnose things quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are putting html in app directly. 
 You can move below code in a template and use ng-include to add this template in you all views.

```
<div class="bottom-bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/pages/#/">Retour {{bottomBar}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is because your controller scope is present in this div with ngView. Therefore anything outside this div won't have scope binding.

```
<div class="page {{pageClass}}" ng-view></div> <!-- controller active here only -->
```